# select entity from list based on condition and cast it

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have this entities.

```
   List<Option> lstoption1 = new List<Option>();
   Option opt = new Option();
   opt.OptionText = "Text1"; 
   lstoption1.add(opt)

   Option opt2 = new Option();
   opt2.OptionText = "Text2"; 
   lstoption1.add(opt2)


   Option opt3 = new Option();
   opt3.OptionText = "Text3"; 
   lstoption1.add(opt3)
```

I want to select OptionText="Text2" into new Option.so I wrote this.

```
  Option optnew =(from i in lstoption1 where i.OptionText ="Text2" select i) as Option
```

but its throwing an error. How do we do this using linq.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `firstordefault()` so that only one element will be returned.
2. Use `==` instead of `=` operator

   ```
   Option optnew =(from i in lstoption1 where i.OptionText == "Text2" select i).firstordefault()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you would in an if statement, you must use the double = for equality.  My adjustment to your LINQ isn't tested, but should be close to what you need.

```
Option optnew =((from i in lstoption1 where i.OptionText == "Text2" select i).SingleOrDefault()) as Option;
```

You need to indicate that you are only expecting one result from your where clause (SingleOrDefault()).  This means that you will either have a single result, or not (a null) - and since you are casting with an "as Option", a null value is valid and won't throw an exception.